# How to create a localized webpage based on the time-zone of the system in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I want to create a asp.net localized web page in which the UI of the page should be automatically converted to the current culture that is extracted from system's time-zone. For example if I am using that web page in India, my time-zone is GMT+5.30 then the language of the page should be "hn-IN". Same is should be auto converted to Spanish or French. I don't want to put an manual link for selecting the preferred language.

Comment: What about localize based on ip?

Comment: You know that here in Europe in the same timezone there are Rome, Paris, Berlin, Amsterdam, ...

Comment: I'd recommend to use a different way of localization. If you have GMT+1 (my time in Austria) then it should be German as i am in Austria, but it could be French or Italian too (GMT+1). Also Keep in mind that a Timezone has 2 parts (south and North)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with client side scripting using Javascript to determine the Users current timezone. Something like http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp which you can then use to change elements of the page.

```
var d = new Date()
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
```